# integrate $\int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{x}}^1 e^{\frac{y^3}{3}} \, dy \, dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> $$\int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{1}e^{\frac{y^3}{3}} \, dy \, dx$$

So I understand I need to change the integration limits by looking at the domain. I have sketched it

[image]

But how do I know if I need to take the area under the curve or above it?

(in the drawing the area filled with vercital or horizontal lines)

Comment: Take a fixed $x$ value, then draw the vertical line at $x$.  The $y$-values are above $\sqrt{x}$ and below $1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr So it will be $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y^2} e^{\frac{y^3}{3}}dxdy$?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: If you care about accuracy in your sketch, notice there ought to be a vertical tangent at $x=0$ (although you don't actually need to know that to solve this particular problem). $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy a tangent at $x=0$? why?

Comment: @gbox : As I said, you don't actually need to know about that for this particular problem. This curve of course has a tangent line at every point, and what I was saying is that the one at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is vertical.  You can see that by observing that the derivative approaches $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from above.  Or you can observe that $y=\pm\sqrt x$ is the same as $x=y^2$, and the graph of that is a parabola, and then think about how that parabola is situated. In your sketch it doesn't look vertical at that point. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every fixed value of $x$ between $0$ and $1$ corresponds to a vertical line in your sketch.  That vertical line intersects the curve you drew at a height of $\sqrt x$ above the $x$-axis, and intersects the horizontal line above that at a height of $1$ above the $x$-axis; hence as $y$ goes from $\sqrt x$ up to $1$, you're **above** the curve.

If you do the integral in the opposite order, then you think of a fixed value of $y$ corresponding to a horizontal line.  That horizontal line intersects the left boundary of the region you drew at the $y$-axis, which is the line $x=0$, and intersects the curved right boundary when $x=y^2$.  So on that horizontal line, $x$ goes from $0$ up to $y^2$.  Thus you have
$$
\int_0^{y^2} \cdots\cdots\, dx.
$$
This integral is evaluated on every vertical line corresponding to a $y$ value between $0$ and $1$, so that integral is inside another one:
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{y^2} \cdots\cdots \,dx \right) \, dy.
$$

Answer (score 3):

While $x$ varies between $0$ and $1$, $y$ varies between $\sqrt x $ and $1$; hence it is the above region (horizontal lines)

The other region would be $y$ varies between $0$ and $\sqrt x $

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of the integration.

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} \exp\left(\dfrac{y^3}{3}\right)\,dx\, dy$$

> $$  = \int_0^1 y^2 \exp\left(\dfrac{y^3}{3}\right)\,dy$$

Then you can use a $u$ substitution to solve this integral

> $$\int_0^1 \exp(u) \,du$$

Comment: The integral is immediate as we have $\;\int f'\,e^f\;dx=e^f+K\;$